# Fading hints at Paypal Android activities

Tags: android, paypal

Below is the screenshot of the latest PayPal SampleApp from [github](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK): the default "hint" color fades on the background. Tried to apply a custom theme with a darker `textColorHint`, but it doesn't seem to change anything:

v21/styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.DarkHint" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:textColorHint">#99000000</item>
</style>
```

app manifest

```
<activity android:name="io.card.payment.DataEntryActivity"
          android:theme="@style/AppTheme.DarkHint"/>
```

or even

```
<application
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.DarkHint"
```

Any other way I could try to fix the issue ?

[image: PayPal hint text fading]